# Ubuntu 18.04 server - Network interface name changed after installing PCIe device

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, hardware, pcie

I've got an industrial PC running Ubuntu 18.04.6 server which I've been using for over a year now. It has 2 network interfaces, `enp1s0` and `enp0s31f6`, but only `enp1s0` is in use. `enp1s0` has a static IP address configured and it has survived dozens of reboots like this.

I had to take the PC offline today to install a PCIe license key in it, and after that it didn't come back up on the network. I connected a monitor and keyboard to it and saw that the name of `enp1s0` changed to `enp4s0`, so my Netplan configuration wasn't working anymore.

Why did this happen? Can it be prevented somehow? Preferably, I'd like to leave predictable network interface names enabled and not have to make udev rules. Every other question I found wanted to change the interface name, but I *don't* want it to change.

Here's the relevant dmesg part, but it obviously just shows `enp4s0`, I don't have an earlier one when the interface had its previous name:

```
# dmesg | grep enp
[    4.392702] igb 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth1
[    4.596407] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: renamed from eth0
```

lshw:

```
# lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 03
       serial: 78:d0:04:22:6e:0d
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k duplex=full firmware=3.16, 0x800004d8 ip=192.168.6.80 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:b3000000-b307ffff ioport:3000(size=32) memory:b3080000-b3083fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 31
       serial: 78:d0:04:22:6e:0c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.8-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:127 memory:b3200000-b321ffff
```

And here's my Netplan config file. The only thing I had to change was the interface name, otherwise it looked the same before:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      addresses:
        - 192.168.6.80/23
      gateway4: 192.168.7.254
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.2.10
        search:
          - company.local
    enp0s31f6:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
```